# Best time to see cherry blossoms in Japan?

Tags: japan, sightseeing, seasonal

Where are the cherry trees blooming in Japan? My problem is that I cannot find out when the cherry trees are blooming in Japan. I have searched the internet and cannot find when the cherry trees are blooming in Japan.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Maybe you're talking about Cherry blossoms?

Comment: Sometime from March to May, depending on your latitude. I suggest you read Hokkaido Highway Blues by Will Ferguson: an account of hitching from the south end of Honshu to the North, following the wave of cheery blossom. http://www.amazon.com/Hokkaido-Highway-Blues-Will-Ferguson/dp/1841952885

Answer (score 8):

So it'll depend a little on WHERE in Japan you want to go, as **due to climate conditions, they bloom at slightly different times**.

A regularly updated forecast for this year can be found in a [nice chart online](http://www.jnto.go.jp/sakura/eng/index.php):

[image: Cherry blooming forecast]

([source](http://www.jnto.go.jp/sakura/eng/index.php))

The same page includes the average bloom times for each location in another chart below.

The blossoms may start in April, but they're often at their best during the ['Golden week'](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2282.html).

Comment: Re: "best during Golden Week", that's not correct for most of Japan.  In eg. Tokyo and Osaka, the peak is usually in late March, a mere week of so after the first bloom, and the blossoms will be long gone by May.  Only Hokkaido and the coolest bits of Tohoku will still have blossoms then.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps I should bold my first sentence to be clear :/

Comment: Yes, the season does shift around by a week or two, but no, that doesn't mean the cherry blossoms will *ever* be in full bloom in Tokyo in May, which is a month after the most likely peak.  See average dates here: http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2011_when.html

Comment: @MarkMayo: "latest forecast for this year"? I'm not sure you want to keep coming back to update that choice of phrasing d-;

Comment: @hippietrail it's not accurate? The site updates in a regular basis, so I figure it's a valid sentence, no?

Comment: @MarkMayo: Ah well maybe that's better to say then. The chart actually has dates for this season and the previous season. Some of the dates for Okinawa are in December of the year before too, both of which end up not fitting so well with "for this year". But I wrote my first comment expecting it to be a static charts, and I suppose others would too.

Comment: @hippietrail fair enough, edited content :)

Comment: You get around 2 month window. Either pick the dates if your location is fixed or pick the correct location if your dates are fixed. I wrote a short post about my experience. https://travel.madnik.space/the-famous-sakura-in-japan/

Answer (score 4):

The majority of Japan's major cities (Tokyo, Kyoto, Osaka, Nagoya, Hiroshima, Fukuoka etc) are located on the half of the country that faces the Pacific Ocean.  The climate in most these areas is similar and so most tend to hit full bloom around the first weekend of April.  You can see them coming into full bloom for about a week before this date, and losing their blossoms over the course of the week after this date.

This year will likely be no exception, if you're going up to Tohoku or Hokkaido though they will be later (a couple of weeks to a month, as stated above).

Source: 8 years of living in Japan and loving cherry blossom season!

Comment: And if you're in Okinawa you missed them by a couple of months already (-;